# How can I repair the google recaptcha on my sugarcrm site?

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, sugarcrm

The recaptcha is not displayed the space where it should be displayed is all grey in my sugar crm....

When I click on get another recapcha, nothing happens...
I'm running with suiteCRM the version 7.9.12.
The public and private key I use for this recaptcha works in another recaptcha I had made elsewhere.

[Image of the GoogleReCapcha totally grayed and not functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0novr.png)

I have this message in the console.
[Errors message in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zqmz.png)

I published this problem in this forum 4 months ago but without any follow-up...

```
 "<script type='text/javascript' src='" .
        getJSPath('cache/include/javascript/sugar_grp1_yui.js') . "'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='" .
        getJSPath('cache/include/javascript/sugar_grp_yui2.js') . "'></script>
                        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
                        <script>

     function initCaptcha(){
                            Recaptcha.create('$captcha_publickey' ,'captchaImage',{theme:'custom'});
                            }
                            window.onload=initCaptcha;

                            var handleFailure=handleSuccess;
                            var handleSuccess = function(o){
                                    if(o.responseText!==undefined && o.responseText ==='Success'){
                                            generatepwd();
                                            Recaptcha.reload();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                            if(o.responseText!=='')
                                                    document.getElementById('generate_success').innerHTML =o.responseText;
                                            Recaptcha.reload();
                                    }
                            }
```

Comment: have you done any debugging? At minimum, have you checked in your browser's Console for errors? Or in the Network tool to see any sign of problems communicating with Google? We can't just guess what errors you are getting...you need to do some actual investigation first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added an image in above you can click on Errors message in the console

Comment: Ok. So the error means it cannot find any variable or function called `Recaptcha`. Where exactly did you get the idea to write the code as you've done above? According to the examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), the variable is called `grecaptcha` not `Recaptcha` and the function you must call is named `render` not `create`. (P.S. That documentation is for Recaptcha version 3, but it seems to be similar for version 2 as well).